# How to write infinite sums of Intervals as a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $r_n$ be an enumeration of rational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\mu$ denote the lebesgue-measure.

Why is the following true?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu((r_n-\frac{1}{n^2}, r_n + \frac{1}{n^2})) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^2}$

How do I know such Equalities? Is there anything I can study or practice, in order to be able to solve such Problems? Even with the Equality given, I don't know why the Sum of this open interval is exactly equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^2}$.

Comment: Are you sure that $\mu$ isn't specifically the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @ManateePink it is, you are right. But does it make a difference in this context?

Comment: It makes a big difference. Do you know what the Lebesgue measure of an interval is?

Comment: @Snildt as far as I can remember, intuitively, it is the product of the sidelenghs of the n-dimensional hyperrectangle. So for an interval [a,b], the lebesgue-measure must be \mu([a,b]) = b - a

Comment: @Snildt  thank you guys! I just used the definition of the Lesesgue-Measure. Now the right Series of the equality makes sense!